# Why are some grid items appearing out of order?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-selectors, css-grid

I am working on a CSS grid layout that looks something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ftL5zw0x/23/ where I don't know how many items I will have.

The layout looks how I want it to but the problem is with the ordering. Every 6th and 7th items appear out of order, they should switch places while the layout stays unchanged. (For example items 6 and 7)

Is there any way I can achieve this through CSS alone?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  grid-gap: 8px;
}

.item {
  background-color: #c4c4c4;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div:nth-child(8n+1),
div:nth-child(8n+3), 
div:nth-child(8n+7),
div:nth-child(8n+8) {
  grid-row: span 1;
}

div:nth-child(8n+2), 
div:nth-child(8n+4),
div:nth-child(8n+5), 
div:nth-child(8n+6) {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">item1</div>
  <div class="item">item2</div>
  <div class="item">item3</div>
  <div class="item">item4</div>
  <div class="item">item5</div>
  <div class="item">item6</div>
  <div class="item">item7</div>
  <div class="item">item8</div>
  <div class="item">item9</div>
  <div class="item">item10</div>
  <div class="item">item11</div>
  <div class="item">item12</div>
  <div class="item">item13</div>
  <div class="item">item14</div>
  <div class="item">item15</div>
  <div class="item">item16</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change your selectors that is the `7th` element that should span not the `6th`

This will push the 6th element to the right following the flow of the grid that is being the position of the previous element `5th`

However we can enforce the position of every `6th` element because we know it's the second column.

That will make the `7th` and `8th` element follow the `6th` element we can fix this with `grid-auto-flow:row dense;`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  grid-gap: 8px;
}

.item {
  background-color: #c4c4c4;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div:nth-child(8n+1),
div:nth-child(8n+3),
div:nth-child(8n+6),
div:nth-child(8n+8) {
  grid-row: span 1;
}

div:nth-child(8n+2),
div:nth-child(8n+4),
div:nth-child(8n+5),
div:nth-child(8n+7) {
  grid-row: span 2;
}

div:nth-child(8n+6) {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">item1</div>
  <div class="item">item2</div>
  <div class="item">item3</div>
  <div class="item">item4</div>
  <div class="item">item5</div>
  <div class="item">item6</div>
  <div class="item">item7</div>
  <div class="item">item8</div>
  <div class="item">item9</div>
  <div class="item">item10</div>
  <div class="item">item11</div>
  <div class="item">item12</div>
  <div class="item">item13</div>
  <div class="item">item14</div>
  <div class="item">item15</div>
  <div class="item">item16</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. Nice work!

Comment: @PaulAlexandru also not that the whole selector using `grid-row: span 1;`can be removed since by default an element will span 1 cell

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes that is correct, But i didn't want to throw it away as he might have other uses for it.

Comment: Yes, I will remove it in the actual project, I had it there just to be clear on what I wanted to do. Thanks again, guys!

Answer (score 0):

Although every 6th and 7th item *appear* out of order, they are not out of order.

Look at item 5 (a `span 2` item). The top half is on row 2 and the bottom half is on row 3. But it gets placed on row 2.

Same for item 6. The top half is on row 2 and the bottom half is on row 3. It gets placed on row 2, which comes before row 3, which is where item 7 gets placed.

So, 6 is placed before 7, 15 is before 16, etc., and everything is placed in order.

[image]

Targeting these items with CSS is not a big deal.

```
div:nth-child(8n+6),
div:nth-child(8n+7) {}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  grid-gap: 8px;

}

.item {
  background-color: #c4c4c4;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div:nth-child(8n+1), div:nth-child(8n+3), div:nth-child(8n+7), div:nth-child(8n+8) {
  grid-row: span 1;
}

div:nth-child(8n+2), div:nth-child(8n+4), div:nth-child(8n+5), div:nth-child(8n+6) {
  grid-row: span 2;
}

div:nth-child(8n+6),
div:nth-child(8n+7) {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">item1</div>
  <div class="item">item2</div>
  <div class="item">item3</div>
  <div class="item">item4</div>
  <div class="item">item5</div>
  <div class="item">item6</div>
  <div class="item">item7</div>
  <div class="item">item8</div>
  <div class="item">item9</div>
  <div class="item">item10</div>
  <div class="item">item11</div>
  <div class="item">item12</div>
  <div class="item">item13</div>
  <div class="item">item14</div>
  <div class="item">item15</div>
  <div class="item">item16</div>
</div>
```

But then what? Not sure there's any easy solution to the problem, but [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61349566/3597276) looks quite good.